# react updating state in an array inside of an object which is inside of another array

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a new task for each person separately on the task list. I successfully get the id for each person and add new task to that person info array in addItem function and I'm even able to see my new state being updated with the correct value when I log to the console. However, I'm getting this error-> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Also, what's the best way to update the state in these kind of cases? I know that spread operator or Object.assign is being used a lot but what should I think about when there is a nested levels of state?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        id: 0,
        title: "Winnie",
        info: [
          "Buy eggs from the grocery store",
          "Return text books to the campus",
          "Buy eggs from the grocery store",
          "Return text books to the campus"
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Maggie",
        info: [
          "Finish cleaning before 11 pm",
          "See if Michael has any recommendations",
          "Buy eggs from the grocery store",
          "Return text books to the campus"
        ]
      }
  };

  addItem = id => {
    const enteredTask = prompt("Please enter a task");

    this.state.data.map(d => {
      if (d.id == id) {
        d.info = [...d.info, enteredTask];
        console.log("d info", d);
        this.setState({
          data: [...this.state.data, d.info]
        });
        console.log("state is", this.state.data);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 className="header">Dashboard</h3>
        <div className="card-parent">
          {this.state.data.map(d => {
            return <Card key={d.id} info={d} addItem={this.addItem} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card-style">
        <h4 className="card-header">{this.props.info.title}</h4>
        {this.props.info.info.map(i => {
          return <p className="card-info">{i}</p>;
        })}
        <button
          onClick={() => this.props.addItem(this.props.info.id)}
          className="card-button"
        >
          Add New Task
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to check for `this.state.data` before you apply `.map` to it.
`{this.state.data && this.state.data.map(d => { //code`

Comment: this looks really weird: don't `setState` while iterating: aggregate your changes, then issue a _single_ `setState`. Looking at your code: the new array your `map` is supposed to generate just gets thrown away, and instead of you try to change the state _while working with it_ so that's no good.

Answer (score 1):

This error is probably coming from: `this.props.info.info.map` inside your render function. I think you intended it to be `this.props.info.map` instead.

Ideally you can do `this.props.info && this.props.info.map`. 
Just make sure whatever array you've in your code, before mapping over it you check for it's existence first. Do this before mapping any array in your code

```js
// for any array named arr
arr && arr.map(//your operation)
```

Even it `arr = []`, i.e. has no elements, it will still be true when it's typecasted to boolean.

Coming to the second part, the idea behind *spread operator* or *Object.assign* is to change reference, allowing react to update state.

But note, both these methods change only reference to one level down. So for nested objects or more specifically for your case, you can do the following:

```
  addItem = id => {
    const enteredTask = prompt("Please enter a task");
    const newData = [...this.state.data];  // changed array's reference here

    // changed reference of nested object
    newData[id].info = [...d.info, enteredTask]; 
    this.setState({ data: newData });
 };
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes the error is coming from there but that's not a typo, I know it's a poor naming but I actually meant this.props.info.info, it works when I don't try to add a new item.

Comment: Check for array and then map over it. I'll update the answer to help you understand.

Comment: Thanks, I slightly changed your approach to make it work. I'll upvote your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `this.state.data` before using `map` in your `render` method to stop the error that you are getting:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3 className="header">Dashboard</h3>
      <div className="card-parent">
        {this.state.data && this.state.data.map(d => {
          return <Card key={d.id} info={d} addItem={this.addItem} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

...and the same in the `render` method of your `Card` component:

```
{this.props.info.info && this.props.info.info.map(i => {
  return <p className="card-info">{i}</p>;
})}
```

You can then update your `addItem` method to call `setState` after updating the data rather than in each iteration of `map`:

```
addItem = id => {
  const enteredTask = prompt("Please enter a task");

  const newData = this.state.data.map(d => {
    if (d.id == id) {
      d.info = [...d.info, enteredTask];
    }
    return d;
  });

  this.setState({ data: newData });
};
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm still getting the same error. The error is actually not generated on the App class but on the Card class on this line this.props.info.info.map. If I check the same thing here same as this.props.info & this.props.info.info.map then I can't see the tasks being rendered

Comment: I tested this code and seems to work fine. Do you still get the error? Did you get the second `.info`? ...so `this.props.info.info && this.props.info.info.map(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer based on Knick's suggestion with a slight change, thanks everybody for helping

```
  addItem = id => {
    const enteredTask = prompt("Please enter a task");
    let new_arr = [...this.state.data];

    this.state.data.map(d => {
      if (d.id === id) {
        new_arr[id].info = [...d.info, enteredTask];
        this.setState({
          data: new_arr
        });
      }
    });
  };
```